# Bandwidth issue of my gigabyte network

Tags: networking, bandwidth, gigabit-ethernet

Every device in the network supports gigabyte transferring. All wires are CAT6 (flatten wire).

The maximum bandwidth can only achieve 1000Mbps for less than 24 hours. The next day when I tested the bandwidth it failed to 100Mbps.

This was normal temporarily.

```
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.07 GBytes   110 MBytes/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.07 GBytes   110 MBytes/sec                  receiver
```

After a night it became to,

```
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   113 MBytes  11.3 MBytes/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.02  sec   112 MBytes  11.2 MBytes/sec                  receiver
```

I cannot figure out the cause of this issue and I post the problem I experienced here for help. Thanks, guys.

PS: I re-deployed the devices. Now, the home gateway connects to a router, and the router connects to a switch which finally connects to my iMac. I tested the bandwidth on this iMac.

Copied (have to find the right place to post this thread) from [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1139025/bandwidth-issue-of-my-gigabyte-network)

Comment: How is your test done, to another local machine/router or to an internet destination? What is the Ethernet link speed your device shows, does it change away from gigabit?

Comment: Hello, Yisroel. The test is done within my internal network. The traffic never leaves the home gateway which is connected to the outside. I see that both ethernets of my router and my iMac are in 1000Mbase mode, no matter whether the actual speed is 1000Mbps or 100Mbps. Earlier, I unplugged all LAN wires on the router and soon re-plug them, except I switched the wire to my switch (to iMac) from LAN port 4 to LAN port 1. Then, I found the speed was 1000Mbps again. I don't understand the logic behind.

Comment: What's the 2nd device you're testing with (the destination)? To note, in your slow tests it's not reaching even 100, so not sure why you're thinking that it's failing to 100 megabit network link.

Comment: I set up iperf3 sever end on the home gateway (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), and the client end on my iMac (homebrew). I started the transfer from the iMac both directly and reversely. Results were same.

Comment: So the traffic isn't local. Anything passing a router will be bottlenecked by the router's processing speed ("routing" for sure, but potentially firewall and more as well) and more factors. Any chance to test a real local test to another local device?

Comment: BTW, can you explain the purpose of this Ubuntu "home gateway" device? That's not your typical network setup (of **modem** > router > switch > computers)

Comment: Sure. I can test the traffic between my iMac and my MacBook Pro (wirelessly). They are in the same subnet, although the AP which MacBook Pro accesses and my iMac are connected to a same switch.

Comment: iMac initiated and to MBP
`[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   166 MBytes  16.6 MBytes/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.01  sec   166 MBytes  16.6 MBytes/sec                  receiver`
iMac initiated to MBP but reversely
`[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec   687 MBytes  68.5 MBytes/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   683 MBytes  68.3 MBytes/sec                  receiver`

Comment: The home gateway serves as a modem.

Comment: Wireless tests aren't very relevant as the are restrained by the wireless connection, nothing Ethernet to test on your local (switch) network? What does "serves as a modem" mean, which function does it do that the router doesn't? (Typically modems would be ISP devices to convert the Coax/DSL/Fiber signal to an Ethernet signal, that's all functionality a 'modem' is supposed to do.)

Comment: Yep. I think I have to re-check it again several days later.

Answer (score 0):

Check the indicated link speeds. Your figures seem to indicate that one of the involved links falls back to 100 Mbit/s.

Gigabit links falling back to Fast Ethernet are a cable problem: 1000BASE-T requires all four pairs to work, 100BASE-TX works with only two of the pairs.

Falling back due to cable problems isn't specified by any standard, but quite common with modern ports (due to the ubiquity of Broadcom chipsets with their *Ethernet@Wirespeed* feature).

So, you should check which link degrades to 100 Mbit/s link rate and fix the cable.

Comment: Hmmm.
`media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
 status: active
`
Looks like this is the issue. However, it had never been so before when the actual speed is 100 Mbps. It was the first time to show a drop from 1000Base-T to 100Base-TX. I don't know why. Anyway, thank you. I need to keep re-checking it for more time.